# how to add path parameter to system() function in c++

Tags: c, firewall

i want to add new rule windows firewall , am using `system()` function for this in c

normally cmd command for that would be

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="myp" dir=in action=allow 
program="C:\test\Project1.exe"
```

so i want to know how i can insert it to `system();`  function i try it but no success , i mean double quotes not works like

`system("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="myp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\\test\\Project1.exe"");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the double quote - `\"` to use it inside a string.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for a list of other escape sequences.

Your command would then become

```
system("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"myp\" dir=in action=allow program=\"C:\\test\\Project1.exe\"");
```

Comment: please give example use above statement     netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="myp" dir=in action=allow program="C:\test\Project1.exe"

Comment: @darkworks I've updated my answer to include this.  Basically, you just need to change each `"` in the command to `\"`

Comment: it not work :(  am unable to add rule with the your escape sequence setup

Comment: That is the correct way to escape double quotes.  Are you sure that the command in your question works if entered directly at the command line?  If your question contains any typos, I'll have copied them into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape quotes.

```
system("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"myp\" dir=in action=allow program=\"C:\\test\\Project1.exe\"");
```